# Radio button stays checked after reload using Javascript and PHP session

Tags: javascript, php, session, radio-button

Since I already know how to use the $_GET to store value from a radio button, this time I wanted it to be stored in a PHP session. The page reloads after clicking a button. I used javascript and PHP to do this. What I intended to do was the value from the radio button when clicked goes to the post() function. The post() sends the value to the Test.php file through $.post. The test.php file sends back the value to be stored in the variable a which will later output in the PHP session variable. The $state will be used to make the radio buttons stay checked after reload. However, the code has an error as it does not let me click any of the radio buttons and after clicking one, the whole page stops working and other buttons cannot be clicked anymore.

```
<script>
     function post(){
       var eqstate = $('#state').val();

       $.post('test.php', {statevalue:state},
       function(data){
         var a = data.value;
       });
     }
</script>

 <?php
  $_SESSION['state']="<script> document.write(a)</script>";
  $state=$_SESSION['state'];
  ?>

 <span style="margin-left:35px;">STATE</span><br><br>
 <form>
 <input type="radio" name="state" id="state" value="allstate" onclick="post();" <?php echo 
 $state==='allstate' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> All State <br>
 <input type="radio" name="state" id="state" value="new" onclick="post();" <?php echo $state==='new' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> New EQ: <br>
 <input type="radio" name="state" id="state" value="old" onclick="post();" <?php echo $state==='old' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Old EQ: <br>
 <input type="radio" name="state" id="state" value="unknown" onclick="post();" <?php echo $state==='unknown' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Unknown State: <br>
 </form>
```

Test.php code:

```
<?php
 $a=$_POST['statevalue'];
  echo $a;
  ?>
```

Comment: id's should be unique and you need to get the value of the item clicked. also you're not using the eqstate variable

Comment: Thanks. I'll take note of it.